# has_one relation, how database will looks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-one, has-one

If I have:

```
class Person

   has_one :address

end

class Address
    belongs_to :person
end

Controller:

def new

@person = Person.new

@person.build_address

end
```

**How should my database look? Where will the foreign key be?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Person
   has_one :address
end

class Address
    belongs_to :person
end
```

It means that in `addresses` table in db there is `person_id INTEGER` column.

**PS**

you can look into your migration file. It should be named as XXXXXXXX_create_addresess.rb

Answer (score 2):

The addresses table needs to have a person_id column

Answer (score 1):

Simple rule of thumb, the class that belongs_to has the foreign key.